# RSelenium and findElements with inspect element use

Tags: r, web-scraping

I would like some help in trying to get each verse of this bible chapter from the following website as a row of strings in a dataframe.

I am struggling to find the correct element/don't know how to use findElements() in conjunction with inspect element in the browser. Any indication of how to do this generally for other bits too, e.g. cross references/footnotes would be great...(note the cross references can be seen by adjusted the 'page options' by clicking on the cog near the top of the page

Below is the code I have attempted.

```
chapter.url <- "https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+50&version=ESV"
library(RSelenium)
RSelenium:::startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(chapter.url)
webElem <- remDr$findElements('id','passage-text')
```

Comment: You forgot to add `remDr$open()`.

Comment: Ah yes sorry...will add now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally I would target the relevant HTML. Inspecting the page with firefox firebug or something similar we see:

[image]

The relevant HTML snippet is `<div class="version-ESV result-text-style-normal text-html ">`.
So we could find the element with class `version-ESV`:

```
chapter.url <- "https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+50&version=ESV"
library(RSelenium)
RSelenium:::startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(chapter.url)
webElem <- remDr$findElement('class', 'version-ESV')
webElem$highlightElement() # check visually we have the right element
```

The `highlightElement` method gives us visual confirmation that we have the required block of HTML. Finally we can get this snippet of HTML using the `getElementAttribute` method:

```
appData <- webElem$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]
```

this HTML can then be parsed for the verses using the `XML` package.

UPDATE:

The various verses contained in a `span` with an `id` which starts with "en-ESV-" we can target this using `'//span[contains(@id,"en-ESV-")]` for an XPATH. However within these code blocks we only want the child nodes that are text nodes. Once we find these text nodes we wish to paste them together seperating with spaces:

```
appXPATH <- '//span[contains(@id,"en-ESV-")]'
appFunc <- function(x){
  appChildren <- xmlChildren(x)
  out <- appChildren[names(appChildren) == "text"]
  paste(sapply(out, xmlValue), collapse = ' ')
}
doc <- htmlParse(appData, encoding = 'UTF8') # specify encoding
results <- xpathSApply(doc, appXPATH, appFunc)
```

with the following results:

```
> head(results)
[1] "Then Joseph  fell on his father's face and wept over him and kissed him."                                                                                                                                                   
[2] "And Joseph commanded his servants the physicians to  embalm his father. So the physicians embalmed Israel."                                                                                                                 
[3] "Forty days were required for it, for that is how many are required for embalming. And the Egyptians  wept for him seventy days."                                                                                            
[4] "And when the days of weeping for him were past, Joseph spoke to the household of Pharaoh, saying,  “If now I have found favor in your eyes, please speak in the ears of Pharaoh, saying,"                                   
[5] "‘My father made me swear, saying, “I am about to die: in my tomb  that I hewed out for myself in the land of Canaan, there shall you bury me.” Now therefore, let me please go up and bury my father. Then I will return.’”"
[6] "And Pharaoh answered, “Go up, and bury your father, as he made you swear.”"
```

Comment: Thanks for that! that is useful...I'm not a huge expert on XML either...how would one go about extracting each verse as a row from the `appData` object?

Comment: I have given a brief example of extracting the verses from the resulting HTML code block using an appropriate XPATH. The first verse is not marked with a class and would probably be easiest dealt with seperately.

Comment: Would it please be possible to explain how you got `['//sup[@class = "versenum"]/following-sibling::text()']`?

Comment: I have simplified the XPATH. The first verse is now included. Two steps are required. First identify the verse code blocks then pasting together the test nodes contained within.

Comment: Sorry to keep adding to the issue...but how do you deal with the quotation marks that seem to come out funny....?

Comment: You can specify the `encoding` when running `htmlParse`. I have ammended the code.

Comment: The code looks great, but if changing the chapter url to `"https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+2&version=ESV"` instead, then the output looks wrong, as it is taking the some headings instead of the verse, and also when there is some slightly different formatting in the verse, only the first line is taken...any ideas how to fix these issues for Genesis 2?

Comment: Sorry it is rather none regular. The first verse for example doesnt have an id here and the heading does etc. Plus there are `class = poetry` introduced etc.